# Laravel 4 - Invalid column name 'id'

Tags: laravel, find, laravel-4, primary-key, eloquent

I have already defined

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

in User model.

And

```
User::find(1);
```

works perfectly with new $primaryKey.

But when I try to submit

```
$user = User::create(array(
     'email'    => $email,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => Hash::make($password),
     'code' => $code,
     'active'   => 0
));
```

I still get error: **Invalid column name 'id'**.

Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: did primary key in user table called  user_id ?

Comment: In your migrations, does your table contain a primary key name?

Comment: Yes, in users table the are primary key column user_id. As I said - User::find(1) works fine, but User::create doesn't. It's like User::create are using different model, not the User.php where the $primaryKey = 'user_id' is defined, because User::find(1) works well with that, giving out all the data. And I am calling both in same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model just set

```
public function getKeyName(){
    return "user_id";
}
```